# Standard Report but Creating an Exact Same Custom Report Won't Show the Same Results

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

I was playing around with reports and I used one of the standard reports Contacts & Accounts. It generated results.

I then tried going into custom report types and did the same thing. I  selected Contact as the primary object and then Account as the secondary. After saving it, I selected this report type when creating the report but it generated 0 rows.

Here is how the custom report went.

[image]

Even if I changed it to the second option, the report would still have no rows returned.

And here is what the resulting custom report looks like. I added no filters.

[image]

And here is the resulting rows if I just selected the standard Contacts & Accounts report.

[image]

Any suggestions as to why this might happen? I thought the custom report had the same logic as the standard report...

UPDATE:

Here are the "folders" that I see on the custom report type.

[image]

And here are the "folders" that I see on the standard Contacts & Accounts report (there might be some additional things that my org customized that might not appear on some standard reports...).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to select Account as a Primary Object.

It's because when you have a `Lookup Relationship` field on the object anything you select in there is like a parent for the record, so when you want to see all `Contacts` related to `Account`, you have to use `Account` as a base to see all children. The reason you had `Accounts` relationship name available when you started with `Contact` as Primary is because you have `Lookup relationship` field to `Contact` in your `Account` object.

Comment: It seems to be working now. But why does switching it around make it work? I thought Salesforce said if I want a Contacts & Account, Contacts should be the primary object.

Comment: It's because when you have a Lookup Relation field on the object anything you select in there is like a parent for the record, so when you want to see all Contacts related to Account, you have to use Account as a  base to see all children.
The reason you had `Accounts` relationship name available when you started with Contact as Primary is because you have Lookup relationship field to Contact in your Account object.

Comment: @Oleksiy, you should [edit](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/152413/edit) that comment into your answer.

Comment: @battery.cord done

Answer (score 0):

In first report CreatedDate is in current FQ is set. Try to remove that and then run report. It will display same result.

[image]

I tried to create same report nd when I remove the date filter and in Range select ALL Time it display the result.

Comment: I tried but it didn't... I changed the date to CreatedDate but nothing showed up. :(

Comment: @akcorp2003 check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update! However, I did the exact same thing previously and still no results. I tried it again but still no luck.

Comment: @akcorp2003 just FYI in report creation I have select second option Record A may or may not have related B record.